# Sorting ArcMap legend alphabetically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, layouts

I'm using the ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop to make a map and I have many legends.

Is it possible to sort legend in alphabet order without manually reordering it?

Comment: Are all the legend label values you want to sort alphabetically coming from one or multiple labels?  In any event, I think a picture of your unsorted legend will be helpful for you to include within your question.